# HDD hardware failure diagnostics

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery, hardware-failure, diagnostic

Suppose we have a modern HDD that doesn't get recognized by either the operating system or the BIOS. We know for sure that it's not an issue with cables/motherboard/power supply/etc.

And now suppose we work for a data recovery lab.

1. What diagnostic procedures are out there to figure out which particular part of HDD has failed?
2. Is there any specific hardware/software kit around that is used by data recovery labs to diagnose the issue?

I Googled this for multiple days, but there is not much information on this topic. The most informative pieces of information are "check out SMART data" and "different failures have different sounds when HDD is turned on". Which don't seem to be what people do in data recovery labs.

*Please don't suggest to send the HDD to a data recovery lab. With this question, I'm looking to learn a new area of knowledge related to the field of my education, not to recover some data from a failed HDD.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the drive is not recognized by the BIOS software recovery techniques are not possible. The problem is either the drive electronics or drive motor, read-write heads, etc. Few amateurs get past this stage and most that do fail in their attempts. The next stage of investigation would depend much on information supplied by the customer about the circumstances of the failure. Go the wrong direction here and the drive may be further damaged. Experience plays a big role here.

There is special hardware, tools, and software that is used. But it is meant for professional use and priced accordingly. The market is small and that ensures prices will be high.

Commercial data recovery companies don't talk much about this. They have invested much time and money to learn this and they aren't about to give this information away. Most amateurs wouldn't understand anyway. There is an old saying that is very relevant - "A little knowledge is a dangerous thing". Whatever an amateur would learn would only be a little knowledge.

I am not a data recovery professional but have only read about it.

Comment: `As the drive is not recognized by the BIOS software recovery techniques are not possible.`: Yes, but I think there should be software that goes beyond reading the SMART data (probably manufacture specific one) that could talk with HDD controller and read more specific data about which hardware part is detected to be failed.

Comment: `There is special hardware, tools, and software that is used.`: Could you point to a top companies that offers those and/or the best sources of information you discovered?

Comment: The drive controller could tell you very little about what hardware has failed, assuming it is even functional. The software and tools I mentioned are designed for professionals with expert knowledge. I don't have that level of knowledge and don't know who sells them. This is the realm of professionals and amateurs don't get very far. Maintain backups and you should have no need for data recovery.